# Cannot Create queue on Websphere MQ Explorer V7.0

Tags: ibm-mq

I have installed Websphere MQ V7. and created queue manager and channels , but the problem is i cannot create any queues on the explorer and when check in the error log files ,there's no errors thrown

How can i be helped

Answer (score 2):

It sounds as though you can see the queues in Explorer but creating a new queue fails.  If what you meant was that you are unable to get Explorer to connect at all, then please clarify the question.

When you can see queues but can't create them, there's a very good chance that you are getting authorization errors.  You can test this theory by enabling authorization events:

`runmqsc <qmgr name>

ALTER QMGR AUTHOREV(ENABLED)`

If this is the problem then you will see event messages being generated in the `SYSTEM.ADMIN.QMGR.EVENT` queue.

Another way to verify this is to set the MCAUSER of the SVRCONN channel to an administrative value.  If you are using Linux, that would be 'mqm' and on Windows it depends on how you installed it but MUSR_MQADMIN usually works.

`runmqsc <qmgr name>

ALTER CHL(SYSTEM.ADMIN.SVRCONN) CHLTYPE(SVRCONN) MCAUSER('mqm')`

If this solves the problem then it was authorization errors.  Keep in mind that hard-coding the MCAUSER to an administrative value means that anyone connecting to that channel has administrative rights.

If security is important you will want to make sure that any inbound channel with a blank MCAUSER or an administrative account in MCAUSER authenticates connections using SSL or an exit.  Channels for low-privileges access must have a low-privileged account in the MCAUSER or else they allow administration.  These include channels of type RCVR, RQSTR, CLUSRCVR and SVRCONN, and specifically those named `SYSTEM.DEF*` and `SYSTEM.AUTO.*` as well as any user-defined channels.  For much more discussion of WMQ security, please see the *WMQ Hardening* presentation at https://t-rob.net/links/ or post questions here on SO.

Comment: I tried this but with no luck.  Ended up creating the queues on the command line.

Comment: This answer describes how to diagnose the problem, not how to fix it.  When you say you tried it but no luck, what does that mean, exactly? You weren't able to diagnose the problem or that you diagnosed the root cause but couldn't fix it? What did the authorization event say?

Comment: Didn't see any events in SYSTEM.ADMIN.QMGR.EVENT.   And tried to run the channel as mqm and that didn't work (channel didn't start after that).

Comment: Wow. If the channel doesn't start as mqm, there's something else going wrong. Like if the channel has `MAXMSGL(10)` or has some other alteration designed to block it from starting, wrong port, listener hung, or other issues.